# Using ternary operator inside a function in js

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, control-flow

I've got a question: whenever the code runs the output is false. Why?

```
    function isGreaterThan (numberOne, numberTwo) {
  switch (isGreaterThan) {
    case numberOne > numberTwo:
      return true;
      break;
    default:
      return false;
      break;
  }
}
console.log(isGreaterThan(67, 2));
```

Comment: You are you using a `switch` to do what an `if` would do best ? `switch` is meant for a "list" of possible options.

Comment: This is not a ternary operator example.

Comment: why not return the boolean expression instead of testing it and deciding to return `true` when it is `true`, and `false` when it is `false`? I mean: `return numberOne > numberTwo` is all you seem to need.

Comment: Cause `isGreaterThan` is a *function* and comparing it to a *boolean* with `case true` or `case false` will never match.

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify this, to avoid the misuse of the switch statement:

```js
function isGreaterThan (numberOne, numberTwo) {
  return numberOne > numberTwo;
}
console.log(isGreaterThan(67, 2));
```

Your switch statement is incorrect, in that you need to pass in a condition, and evaluate the outcome in each case statement.

Answer (score 2):

This code is rather confused. For one thing, you're feeding to `switch` a reference to the function it lives in, not a numerical value.

You can greatly simplify the situation like so:

```
function isGreaterThan (numberOne, numberTwo) {
  return numberOne > numberTwo; //return the result of the comparison
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is clearly not working as expected, because you are using a `switch` the wrong way.

First of all, you are switching using the function itself as an expression

```
switch (isGreaterThan) {
```

Then, you are comparing it with another expression

```
 case numberOne > numberTwo:
```

This is the equivalent of

```
if ( isGreaterThan == (numberOne > numberTwo))
```

And this check will never be true, because `isGreaterThan` is not even a boolean, but `(numberOne > numberTwo)` is

So this switch will always fallback to the default statement

```
default:
      return false;
      break;
```

That's why this function will always return `false`

As already mentioned from others, your function could work in this simple form

```
function isGreaterThan (numberOne, numberTwo) {
  return numberOne > numberTwo; 
}
```

Now, if you want an advise, I really think you don't understand how `switch` works, so please take a step back and [learn](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) how it's supposed to work. There was really no reason to use switch in this case.

By the way, a ternary operator (as mentioned in the title) in your case would work like

```
(numberOne > numberTwo) ? true : false
```